# Android Textview setTextIsSelectable not work with calling setAutoLinkMask

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a selectable textview, but I find out the text select event not working when I am using **setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL)**,

following is my code:

```
 TextView tvContent;
 ...
 tvContent.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
 tvContent.setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance());
 tvContent.setTextIsSelectable(true);
 ...
```

and I also try to use:
`Linkify.addLinks(tvContent, Linkify.ALL);`

but it seem doesn't work.
May I know if there have any solution about this?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try for  **android:autoLink="web"** instead of *Linkify*?

Answer (score 1):

I find out the issue root cause is not related to those code, those this code is work! Thanks all.